# Resolve profile based properties file into spring tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

Into my spring `RootConfig` class I use properties file based on my spring profile:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/app.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/app-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@ComponentScan(...)
public class RootConfig {   

    @Bean // just because you will ask about it
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Now I want to write test class that use such configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RootConfig.class)
public class RootConfigTest {

    @Test
    public void testContext() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

But my context is failed to start: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` because

`Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in string value "classpath:properties/app-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"`

And this is web application, so originally my spring profile configured at:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", getSpringProfilesActive());
    }

}
```

`getSpringProfilesActive()` - is a static method, that read System property and not depend on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev")` is set as part of `WebAppInitializer` which is not getting invoked when you run your test case, set the `spring.profiles.active` to `dev` before invoking the test, as follows:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RootConfig.class)
public class RootConfigTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setSystemProperty() {
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }

    @Test
    public void testContext() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: doh, I already trying something similar but not with `@BeforeClass` and `static`. Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably during your tests run `WebAppInitilizer` haven't started. And property SPEL may not be evaluated correctly inside `@PropertySource`. You can try to determine you profile inside `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

```
 @ActiveProfiles("test")
public TestClass {
 ...
}

@Configuration
public class PropertySourcesConfig {

 @Profile("dev")
 public static class DevConfig {
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   pspc.setLocations(new Resources[] {
    "app - dev.properties"
   });
   return pspc;
  }
 }


 @Profile("test")
 public static class DevConfig {
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   pspc.setLocations(new Resources[] {
    "app - test.properties"
   });
   return pspc;
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: I've try and get the same exception.